# How to take substring from new line C#

Tags: c#

I have a file in the below format

```
abc,def,ghi,365.23475,bk,2324,1,
nhk,73.9083,knd,lees,73.584,df,100,
```

I need to take the value that comes after the fourth ',' from the second line.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
string input = "abc,def,ghi,365.23475,bk,2324,1,\nnhk,73.9083,knd,lees,73.584,df,100,";
string result = input.Split('\n')[1].Split(',')[4]; //73.9083
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLine(PATH_TO_THE_FILE);
string result;

if (lines.Count > 0) {
   var temp = lines[1].Split(',');
   if (temp.Length > 3) { 
     result = temp[3];
   } else {
     result = null;
   }
} else {
   result = null;
}
```